# Qt 4.5 .NET framework dependency

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, qt, qt4, dependencies

I'm currently developping an application with Qt 4.5 on Windows Vista and Visual Studio 2008 as IDE.

The problem is that the program crashes on Windows XP SP2 (works perfectly with XP SP3 and Vista). This can be fixed installing the .NET framework 3.5, but I want to avoid that.

Is there a way to prevent that given that I have to use the Visual Studio compiler?

**EDIT 2010/02/11:**

Just stumbled upon [that](http://qtweb.net/smf/index.php?topic=212.0;wap2):

> To avoid dependencies to CRT
>   (mscvp90.dll and mscvr90.dll), Qt
>   Framework must be re-compiled with -MT
>   switches to compiler.

Comment: QT itself does not need .NET, and a VS C++ application also doesn't.  Are you sure you're building a pure C++, and not a C++/CLR application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the C++ Runtime Redistributables instead?? 
AFAIK no .net assembly is needed for a Qt Application, but you need the C++ Runtime.